# Clean url with several params in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am a newbie in nginx. The question is how to rewrite url with query string to 'clean' url:

for one parameter:

```
host.com?page.html/param1=value1  <- host.com/page/value1
www.host.com?param1=value1        <- www.host.com/page/value1
```

for two parameters:

```
host.com?page.html/param1=value1&param2=value2 <- host.com/page/value1/value2
www.host.com?param1=value1&param2=value2       <- www.host.com/page/value1/value2
```

for n parameters:

```
host.com?page.html/param1=value1&param2=value2..&paramN=valueN <- host.com/page/value1/value2/../valueN
www.host.com?param1=value1&param2=value2..&paramN=valueN       <- www.host.com/page/value1/value2/../valueN
```

Comment: What will you get for `www.host.com/?param3=val3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters, (aka arguments or query strings) are not directly seen as part of the URL for nginx rewrites. Instead, they are saved as variables that can be accessed, tested against, and inserted into the resulting URL.

The name they are saved as is $arg_.  So, in your first example, you would want to redirect them like so:

```
rewrite ^/page.html$ /page/$arg_param1? permanent;
```

I would not suggest performing rewrites on arguments directly from your hostname (www.host.com?param1=value1) without some input validation, otherwise you'll end up redirecting EVERYTHING from your homepage.